# Python - how to change list of strings to list of dataframe names

Tags: python

list_2 in code below creates a list of strings. Can I convert these strings to dataframe names so they can be used in the pd.concat statement? Thanks.

```
list_1 = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
list_2 = []

for x in list_1:
    vars()['table_2_1_' + x] = table_2_1.table(x)
    list_2.append('table_2_1_' + x)

table21 = pd.concat([*list_2], axis=1)
```

Comment: Why don't pass your dataframes to `pd.concat` directly? Why do you need to create variables?

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych to automate a much larger process, so I don't need to edit toads of code when I add to or change list_1. There's lots more tables that need to run with for loops on list_1, and being able to automate it on the fly will make life much easier in the long-run. I guess that's the thing with stackoverflow is I can't post the entire project, and have to pare it down the the bare minimum to illustrate the task I need to achieve. It misses out the whole context :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `eval` to convert string to variable

```
list_2 = [eval(x) for x in list2]
```

should work for you